# Force enconding of all files within a Visual Studio solution directly from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, encoding, character-encoding, visual-studio-addins

Any way to convert the encoding of all the files within a VS solution (*.sln) directly inside Visual Studio? (I am using 2008).

Any Add-in for this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily write a VS macro to achieve that. You'd have to [iterate over all projects](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2007/02/20/enumerating-projects-in-a-visual-studio-solution.aspx), then for each project iterate over all project configurations (assuming the change should apply to all), and for each configuration modify [VCProjectConfigurationProperties.CharacterSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcproject.vcprojectconfigurationproperties.characterset.aspx) to your desired encoding.

(The link is from the VS2010 documentation, but should apply to previous VS versions too).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My projects configuration files are set to the desired encoding, but still there are some files within each project that have different encodings.. Ill try to look if I can iterate over all the files and convert to the desired encoding.